# fb:comment does not work on my application

Tags: facebook, comments

I'm a new Facebook developer. I want to add comments box to my application and I follow the tutorial in Facebook wiki. It's not work in my application.

My canvas callback URL is http://122.155.0.71/~facebook/ and I upload `xd_receiver.htm` to root directory.  I am using the following code

```
<script src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/XdCommReceiver.js?2" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php/en_US" type="text/javascript"></script>
<fb:comments> </fb:comments>
<script type="text/javascript">FB.init("b6e07896a1d0889d9784dea150802587", "/xd_receiver.htm");</script>
```

in my application. It not show up. When I view this page with Firebug. I see `<fb:comments> </fb:comments>`. I don't know about xid, where can I create it?

Answer (score 1):

This tag allow user to post comments in my FBML and display these comments on their Wall. But for some cause, comments can not be displayed in users' Wall even they checked the box "Post comment to my Facebook profile".
I don't know what was wrong with the code

I really appreciate if you can help.

This is my FBML: [click here to view](http://www.facebook.com/pages/Unique-Pillow/265852568882?v=app_4949752878&ref=ts)

And this is my code:

```
<fb:comments xid="comment" " canpost="true" candelete="false" numpost="10" publish_feed="true"><fb:title>Comment</fb:title></fb:comments>
```

Comment: Please sign up and vote for this bug here -> http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=13535

I've had this issue for a while. I have two identical apps, same code and same settings, just different keys and urls. On one (old app) "Post comment to my Facebook profile" doesn't work, on the other (new app) everything is perfect.

It doesn't make sense. The more developers vote for this bug, the faster it will be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on an iFrame XFBML application and had trouble getting this to work until I realized what it meant for the fb:comments tag to be an "unsupported" XFBML tag.  To get this working, you have to wrap the fb:comments call in fb:serverFbml tags.

Here's the full code:

```
<fb:serverFbml style="margin-top:15px;">  
            <script type="text/fbml">  
                <fb:fbml> 
                    <fb:comments xid="project_1" publish_feed="false" showform="true" canpost="true" numposts="50" width="467px"><fb:title>Comment on this project</fb:title></fb:comments>
                </fb:fbml>
            </script>
        </fb:serverFbml>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want comment box like this  in my app
http://apps.facebook.com/pollonfb
then it very easy ,

just use following code

```
     <fb:comments xid="Identifier" canpost="true" candelete="false"     returnurl="http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/titans/"> 
      <fb:title>Talk about the Titans</fb:title> 
       </fb:comments
```

XId id simply a unique string to identify your comment box uniquely , For example in my app there is a comment box for each poll , and poll name is xid for their comment box.

Comment: Hi vinayrks! I do follow you but it does not work for me.

Give me full code please.

Comment: what error you are getting
<fb:comments xid="Identifier" canpost="true" candelete="false"     returnurl="http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/titans/"> 
      <fb:title>Talk about the Titans</fb:title> 
       </fb:comments>
it work very fine in my case